# python - обновить словарь в списке

Tags: python, list, dict

Прошу помочь с такой задачей:
Есть массив данных, ниже приведён пример, список из словарей и списка словарей :)
Мне нужно чтобы после получения данных по запросу я смог добавить новый словарь в список `data` если `sku` совпадут, то есть нужно сделать поиск по `sku`, если такой словарь есть списке, то нужно добавить в data еще словарь `{'price': '227690', 'pickupPoints': 'PP18', 'cityID': '111010000'}`, предпологаю, можно сделать как-то через lambda функцию, но пока никак не получается. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи.

```
data = [
    {'sku': '102676538_Realtechhome', 'name': 'LIDER CLASSIC Беллона 4Д белый', 'data': [
                                                                                        {'price': '344990', 'pickupPoints': 'PP16', 'cityID': '515820100'},
                                                                                        {'price': '227690', 'pickupPoints': 'PP6', 'cityID': '391010000'},
                                                                                        {'price': '227690', 'pickupPoints': 'PP18', 'cityID': '111010000'}
                                                                    ...
                                                                                        ]
    },
    {'sku': '123456789_Realtechhome', 'name': 'LIDER CLASSIC Беллона 4Д черный', 'data': [
                                                                                        {'price': '234123', 'pickupPoints': 'PP20', 'cityID': '4645214312'},
                                                                                        {'price': '435341', 'pickupPoints': 'PP3', 'cityID': '234234123'},
                                                                                        {'price': '564121', 'pickupPoints': 'PP1', 'cityID': '756462341'}                        
                                                                    ...
                                                                                        ]
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{'sku': '102676538_Realtechhome',
         'data': [{'price': '344990'}, {'price': '227690'}, {'price': '227690'}]
         },
        {'sku': '123456789_Realtechhome',
         'data': [{'price': '234123'}, {'price': '435341'}]
         }
        ]
sku_new = '123456789_Realtechhome'
data_new = {'price': '564121'}

for index, key in enumerate(data):
    if key['sku'] == sku_new:
        temp = key['data']
        temp.append(data_new)
        key['data'] = temp
        data[index] = key
        break
print(data)

[{'sku': '102676538_Realtechhome', 'data': [{'price': '344990'}, {'price': '227690'}, {'price': '227690'}]},
{'sku': '123456789_Realtechhome', 'data': [{'price': '234123'}, {'price': '435341'}, {'price': '564121'}]}]
```

Comment: так вроде можно одним запросом все ценики получить

Comment: В смысле одним запросом все ценики ? как ?

Comment: как я понял на каспи магазин?

Comment: Да, с ним работаю

Comment: на одну модель можно забрать все ну или почти все ценники

Comment: Все цениики по одному городу, а если по всем городам, то один запрос на каждый город - у меня как раз такой случай :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135079/discussion-between---and-yessey).